# Reading contents of CSV file

Tags: android, csv, bufferedreader

I have made a resource reader with some example code from [here](http://shitmores.blogspot.com/2011/01/android-using-csv-file-as.html). Here is my code...

```
public static void ReadFile() {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));

    String line;
    try {
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            String[] values = line.split(",");

            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(values.toString()));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

my file is read onResume using this code...

```
InputStream file = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.csvfile);
```

and I think i've got it right but when I use the

```
Log.d()
```

utility to read the values  in my csv file (as shown above) I get something else instead

```
10-21 20:38:44.096: DEBUG/input(15223): [Ljava.lang.String;@467bbb20
10-21 20:38:44.104: DEBUG/input(15223): [Ljava.lang.String;@467bbfd8
10-21 20:38:44.104: DEBUG/input(15223): [Ljava.lang.String;@467bc3e0
10-21 20:38:44.112: DEBUG/input(15223): [Ljava.lang.String;@467bc7e8
10-21 20:38:44.112: DEBUG/input(15223): [Ljava.lang.String;@467bcbf0
10-21 20:38:44.112: DEBUG/input(15223): [Ljava.lang.String;@467bcff8
10-21 20:38:44.112: DEBUG/input(15223): [Ljava.lang.String;@467bd400
10-21 20:38:44.120: DEBUG/input(15223): [Ljava.lang.String;@467bd808
10-21 20:38:44.120: DEBUG/input(15223): [Ljava.lang.String;@467bdc10
10-21 20:38:44.120: DEBUG/input(15223): [Ljava.lang.String;@467bde60
```

now I don't know if you can return straight from a BufferReader like this but there seems to be considerably less values here than there are in my csv file.  Here is my csv file

```
001, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000,
001, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000,
001, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000,
001, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000,
001, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000,
001, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000,
001, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000,
001, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000,
001, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000
```

pretty empty i know but am I getting this right or should my log tags return some readable data, if so what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: what are you expecting from "values.toString()" where values is an array?

Comment: @Bipins Well I guess I was expecting the values from my csv to appear maybe there's an extra step that i've missed

Comment: I don't think it will output the strings that the array has. probably 

deepToString() would return all the strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`values.toString()` is only going to output a representation of the values array (its location in memory, in this case). You need to output the individual values. Something like this:

```
for(String s : values) Log.d(TAG, s);
```

EDIT: You're also reinitializing `values` on every run of the while loop. You could either use a StringBuilder, and just keep appending the lines till you reach the end, and then split it into an array, or you could use an ArrayList, store each line in a local String, split it, and append those values to the outer ArrayList.

No problem. :) Just for future readers, I'll be glad to add an example anyway.

With a StringBuilder:

```
public static void ReadFile() {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    try {
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
            sb.append(line);
        }
        String[] values = (sb.toString()).split(",");
        for(String s : values) Log.d(TAG, s);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Or appending per line:

```
public static void ReadFile() {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));
    String line;
    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
            String[] strings = line.split(",");
            for(String s : strings) {
                values.add(s);
            }
        }
        for(String s : values) Log.d(TAG, s);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

These are off my head, so don't fault me if they don't compile as-is, haha.

Comment: Ah yes that works great thanks ^^ but could you give an example or link to a tutorial that shows how to put the values into an array list like you recommended. Thanks ^^

Comment: Just one thing :/ is there a way of sharing ArrayLists between classes (because when I try the normal getValue(){return value;} method my ArrayList seems to lose all its data even as soon as I try to read it from the getValue() method which is in the same class.

Comment: Actually don't worry I just discovered the magic of google ^^